# What’s the source for Kiriyat Shma AlHamita prayers as they are written in the Tehilat Hashem siddur?

Tags: tefilla, jewish-books, prayer-book, chasidut-hasidism, chabad

BH

What’s the source for reciting kiriyat Shma Al Hamita which includes additional prayer besides just the shma as they are laid out in Tehilat Hashem sidur?

The prayers being Ribono Shel Olam, Hashkiveinu, Shma, YaaLeh, Hineh, Yivarechecha, Yoshev, Elokeinu, Ashamnu, Sarnu, Ma Nomar, Ata Yodeah, The Yehi Ratzons four beit din Prayers, Ana Bekoach, Lamenatzeach, Shir Hamaalot, Gad gedud, Im Tishkav, Betov Alin, Liyeshuatecha, Ata Seter li, Todieini Orach, Ata Takum, Ribon Haolamim and Hamapil

And are there earlier authorities that uses these prayers and if yes who are they?

Comment: What do you mean? What the source for reciting the shema at bedtime is, or the way it is in Tehilas Hashem siddur?

Comment: it's the arizal nossach so I think that all chassidims siddur have the same krias shma al hamita
I heard from my mashpia in Brunoy tomchei tmimim in France that the gour rebbe use to pray in a tehilas hashem and wanted to make the tehilas hashem the common nossach of chassidims ...
So to give an answer I think that the earliest authority with this nossach is the arizal 
and the alter rebbe compiled it